# How to fix the Archive does not contain any "PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy" files

Tags: ios, xcode, wwdc, xcode15

### What steps to take to resolve following error related to missing PrivacyInfo:

`The archive does not contain any "PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy" files.`

#### This happens when I try to `Generate Privacy Report` on the archive.

Steps taken to define Privacy Manifest and debug this error:

- Defined the `PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy` and ensured it loading correctly in the Xcode 15 beta 5.
- Added `PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy` to same location as `Info.plist` - Screenshot added below:
- Ensured the target membership of `PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy` to frameworks.
- Archive the framework and also use command line to create distribution `.xcframework` - receiving the error with archive and unable to see `.xcprivacy` file in the `.xcframework` (next question).

Will this `PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy` file be locatable in the archive or final `.xcframework` content on the same level as `Info.plist`? If yes, where to find it?

For reference, [Apple Developer - Privacy manifest files](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files), doesn't mention any other specific steps for Framework. Here is the WWDC-2023 video: [WWDC-2023 Privacy Menifest](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10060/?time=200), which illustrates various steps.

[image: Location of PrivacyInfo]

[image: Privacy-Info-XCPrivacy-file-location]

## Debugging

### Details of debugging with Xcode 15 Beta 8 & with 15 (RC)

Note: The current SDK project has two targets - `RestSDK.framework` and `RestAPI.framework`. This could be interfering with inclusion of Privacy Manifest (`PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy`).

In order to narrow down the issue, took following debugging steps:

1. Installed latest beta 8 `Version 15.0 beta 8 (15A5229m)`
2. Removed old xcprivacy file and added a new with `Command-n` -> `Resource` -> `App Privacy`. Removed all entires but 1 in the new `Privacy Manifest` and added `NSPrivacyTracking` as `false`. Here is how it looks:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyTracking</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeUserID</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeProductPersonalization</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict
```

3. Add the target membership to both `RestSDK.framework` & `RestAPI.framework` (first test), and run the command to create archive: Noticed following `log` on console for `RestAPI.framework`.

```
Copying /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RestSDK-ezfmhpxprnhniqcyumuohtkeojih/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/RestSDK/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Library/Frameworks/RestAPI.framework/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
```

and not a similar `log` for `RestSDK.framework`.

4. Removed the `RestAPI.framework` target membership of `PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy`. Keeping target membership only for `RestSDK.framework`. Triggered the `archive` build with command line and noticed following:

```
Copying /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RestSDK-ezfmhpxprnhniqcyumuohtkeojih/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/RestSDK/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Library/Frameworks/RestSDK.framework/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
```

5. Tried `Generate Privacy Report` and still the same result: `The archive does not contain any` PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy `files.`. Even though, `RestSDK.framework` under `iOS.xcarchive` contains `PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy` ?!! [image: XCPrivacy file in built SDK archive]
6. [Stuck] - Perhaps, I need to add some other keys.

Comment: Linking the same issue, following the suggestions on it: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731541

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you have already tried this, but the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file may not be set as a BundleResource.

You can right-click on the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file and select "Build Action" and set it to BundleResource. Alternatively, you can add this property inside `<ItemGroups>` in your Xamarin.iOS project file:
`<BundleResource Include="PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy" />`

After doing this, build and archive, you should be able to generate the privacy report.

Comment: This worked for me. Having the .xcprivacy file at the same level as the info.plist was insufficient. It seems necessary to manually add it to your target bundle as well.